# NOT LIKE on connect table on mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I have an issue on an sql statement with the mariadb-connect-engine.
Actually it's the NOT LIKE operator which return really strange result.
On this sql request :

```
SELECT ARS_RESSOURCE, ARS_LIBRERES1 FROM ressource WHERE ARS_RESSOURCE NOT LIKE '568614561456%'
```

it would return all the result in the datatable, but it just don't return anythink while :

```
SELECT ARS_RESSOURCE, ARS_LIBRERES1 FROM ressource WHERE ARS_RESSOURCE LIKE '%'
```

or :

```
SELECT ARS_RESSOURCE, ARS_LIBRERES1 FROM ressource WHERE ARS_RESSOURCE LIKE '01%'
```

return all the result asked.

Did i do something wrong or the NOT LIKE operator on a connect table have a diferrent behaviour than on classic connector ?

To be more accurate i use a connect table from mariadb to sqlserver, so maybe this behaviour could be cause by the ODBC driver or something but i don't find any clue at the moment

Comment: What is at the other end of the Connection?  Is it a MySQL/MariaDB table?  Or some other brand?

Comment: @RickJames no it's a SQL server but the not like works on SQL server didn't it ? i just don't understand why this don't work properly except if the request isn't well interpreted in the connect engine actually

Comment: _Some_ forms of "connect" or "federated" require retrieving _all_ the rows before filtering.  (I don't know if `NOT LIKE` falls into this performance pitfall.)

Comment: @RIckJames Anyway thanks to took time to answer,  actually i'm on holiday so i'll try to find a solution when i'm back and ask on mariadb support too, but yeah it's maybe because of the manner that works the not like operator and the connect engine

Answer (score 0):

Actually I opened an issue on the support site of MariaDB and the `NOT LIKE` operator isn't works properly at the moment with the `CONNECT engine` when you use it with the `CONNECTION` argument to connect on an other table.

Here is the link of the opened issue on mariaDB.org:
[link to jira.mariadb.org](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13782?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel)

maybe this could help some people with the same issue.

(to be more accurate this was opened on 10.2.* version of MariaDB and not solve at this date)